# Picture taken with camera does not contain location data but gallery images do when using image_picker

Tags: flutter, dart, exif, imagepicker, flutter-image-picker

I have got an app which includes image_picker to allow the user to choose an image from their gallery or take a photo directly within the app. I need the photo to contain location data so I need the GPS GPSLatitude tag to be inside of the metadata of the image.
When taking a photo just before inputting it through the gallery, the location data is saved to the metadata - whereas taking a photo in app does not contain location despite the setting save location being enabled on my devices camera settings.

Essentially, the code I am using is very simple; using the [exif](https://pub.dev/packages/exif) library to get metadata along with image_picker. Code is below:

```
var image = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
var metadata = await readExifFromBytes(File(image.path).readAsBytesSync());
// check for gps tag
if (metadata.containsKey('GPS GPSLatitude')) {
      print("location enabled");
else{
      print("location disabled");
};
```

It will always print **location disabled** when using camera to get image, but when using gallery with a recent image - it will print **location enabled**
The device I am using is a Xiaomi Redmi Note 8T running on android version 10.

Comment: For a definitive answer, run `exiftool` on images acquired by the two different methods and compare/diff the outputs.

Comment: I have the same problem on my iOS device, is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your app doesn't have permission

You can Use Package permission_handler to obtain it

https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

This to print if the app has permission:

```
if (await Permission.location.isRestricted) {
      print(statuses[Permission.location]);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the problem - I already have location permissions enabled but the location metadata just seems to be very temperamental when taking a photo using camera.

Comment: I have the same problem on my iOS device, is there a solution?

Comment: @Ram I couldn't really find a solution - I posted as an issue and was told the same thing again.. I did find a [comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99817#issuecomment-1064875457) mentioning that a sky had to be visible for GPS data to be saved which did seem to help but other than that I could not find a better solution.